# Error Handling in APL

Tags: error-handling, apl, dyalog

I am currently working on an APL program for a class and have run into an issue with error handling.

In a function I made, I want to check to see that the input is an integer. If it is not, I want to return an error message and not run the rest of the function. So far, I compare to see if it's equal to the floor of itself. If not, I don't want the function to run and want it to stop. It works if I put `4.2` and gives an error message, but doesn't work if I put something like `'A'` in or `'ABCDEF'` and just gives a normal error. I tried making a try catch statement, but it gave me an error when it got to `:Try` in my function.

Which isn't what I want. How can I make it so the function ends with an error message instead of continuing if the input is a character or string? I know I could put the entire code in an if block, but that seems really unnecessary.

My code in plain-text:

```apl
 TESTER Q;error
 :If Q≢⌊Q
     'Possible'
 :Else
     'Not Possible'
 :EndIf
 'Again, Possible'
```

And as a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

If you want to explicitly quit early to avoid enclosing the entire code in a `:If` block, you could do something like:

```
 r←TESTER Q
 :If 0≢⊃0⍴⊂Q ⍝ Q not a simple scalar number
 :OrIf Q≢⌊Q  ⍝ Q not an integer
     r←'Not Possible'
     →0
 :EndIf
 r←'Possible'
```

This works by using APL's prototypes:

`⊂Q` makes sure to handle `Q` as a whole.
`0⍴` makes an empty list of that "type".
`⊃` forces a prototypical element out, which is just like `Q` but with all characters transformed to spaces and all numbers transformed to zeros. Now if `Q` was a simple scalar number, the prototype is `0`, so we test for that.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FHe9GjtgkhrsEhrkEKgVwKVp5pCgaPOhc96mo2eNS75VFXU6DCo965CoEKefklCokKxZm5BTmpCsXJiTmJRQp5pblJqUVAXf5FQH2BIH09XYEKyDryFDLzSlLTQapAAGSbuh9QIiC/uDgzKSdVHSL@qG2SAdAc17wUzzQuiCqECqAr//@HutGYC8bQM4Ux1R3VEUwnZxdXN3UA)

However, it would be more proper for your function to reject the invalid argument by throwing a real error rather than returning or printing a result (which implicitly needs to be understood as an error) so that a function which calls yours can trap the error and take appropriate action. As follows:

```
 r←TESTER Q
 :If 0≢⊃0⍴⊂Q ⍝ Q not a simple scalar number
 :OrIf Q≢⌊Q  ⍝ Q not an integer
     'Not Possible'⎕SIGNAL 11
 :EndIf
 r←'Possible'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY89TsNAEIV7n@J1W4EcIZp0BjvIEvlx4gtM4rWxWO9au0bILUgBLIKgoKThDJxoL2LWEQGmenr63swbqsVR1pJQRW9f3tNlsLDbVx8sYmB2@@a8cMpgdx@YKI3miiON58g1VfxW6esxGk01SLbgWjuCZIasNLWgdk@HJRVSmabcYMqNoYL39vFBuyNptEqjJRIP4ziHb58@bXfv292X7e6S/cUEUjUgmLKqBYfZkCANeVOtuXapuXa5ZMg9dwn@JyRK2fBioIZhM2culDHlWnDmXlrFF7PgEqOR2xLJLM49DI3YL@O5jn3/0/DEO4jj04NkAfuTZ@dhNGHf)

`⎕SIGNAL` throws an error optionally (the left argument) with a custom message, and the right argument is an error number from [this list](http://help.dyalog.com/16.0/Content/Language/Errors/APL%20Errors.htm). Error number 11 is DOMAIN ERROR, which is the appropriate one in this case.

---

I understood that you tried using `:Try` but got an error on that. Due to your tag and your screenshot, I can tell that you are using Dyalog APL, which where the syntax is:

```
 :Trap 4 5 6 10 11 16
     code to try goes here
 :CaseList 4 5
     handling of rank and length errors go here
 :Case 6
     handling of value errors goes here
 :Else
     all other trapped errors are handled here
 :EndTrap
 untrapped errors will throw as usual
```

Again, the error numbers used are those of the above linked list. (`:Try` is a different error trapping system used in APLX.)